# Inheritance with abstract template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Lets say I have an template class and i would like to derive it from an abstract class

I wrote the abstract class declaration as follows:

```
template<typename T, class Derived>
class AbstractClass{

};
```

How do I derive my template class correctly?
At the moment it looks like:

```
template <typename T> 
class TemplateClass{};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are playing with CRTP? The proper way is following:

```
template <typename T> 
class TemplateClass : public AbstractClass<T, TemplateClass<T> > {};
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!
But I still get the following error:
error C3203: 'TemplateClass' unspecialized class template or generic can't be used as a template or generic argument for template or generic parameter 'Derived', expected a real type"

Comment: @user123, of course you do - because I've made a typo. See the update.